# How to add an html element (BODY) class based on taxonomy from logged in user?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users, theming

I'm building a website on Drupal 7 which will be accessible only to registered users. A taxonomy term is referenced to the user account. I need to add a body class based on that taxonomy term so I can personalize the theme's look depending on the logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom module implement hook_preprocess_field().In the given code I am adding a taxonomy term field with uid as class,you can change to your requirement.

```
function mymodulename_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  global $user
  if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'your_taxonomy_term_name') {
    dpm($variables);
    dpm($variables['classes_array']);
    $variables['classes_array'][] = $user->uid;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  global $user;
  $user = user_load($user->uid); // Load user
  $variables['classes_array'][] = $user->field_myfield['und'][0]['tid'];
}
```

It will output the tid not the term name that is being referenced in the user account.